# SQL query to get columns based on value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like below

```
user_id  | month,     | value
---------+------------+--------
1        | 2013-02-01 | 1
1        | 2013-01-01 | 0
1        | 2013-03-01 | 5
2        | 2013-02-01 | 1
```

Supposedly a `user_id` can not have same `month` more than one.

Let's say I can put the months I want to query in the query statement. like below

```
SELECT user_id, (bla bla bla) AS '2013-03-01', (bla bla bla) AS '2013-02-01'
```

How do I get a result like below, with minimum number of queries and post-processing (e.g. using python or php)?

```
user_id  | 2013-03-01 | 2013-02-01 | 2013-01-01 
---------+------------+------------+------------
1        | 5          | 1          | 0
2        | NULL       | 1          | NULL
```

Comment: Google "MySQL dynamic PIVOT".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregates to get the required result set:

```
SELECT user_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN month = '2013-03-01' THEN value END) AS '2013-03-01',
       MAX(CASE WHEN month = '2013-02-01' THEN value END) AS '2013-02-01',
       MAX(CASE WHEN month = '2013-01-01' THEN value END) AS '2013-01-01'
FROM mytable
GROUP BY user_id
```

This works as long there is a *predefined* set of `month` values. Otherwise you have to use dynamic SQL.

[**Fiddle Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a61a6/2)

Comment: Just curious, wha do you mean by dynamic SQL?

Comment: @PetraBarus Dynamic SQL is used when the query is *programmatically* built. In MySQL you can use [prepared statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) to execute such dynamically built queries.